# On insert increment value of one column of unique composite key if duplicate

Tags: mysql

I'm transferring data from db to another. The original table has the following structure (where `key contact` is boolean):

```
+------------+-----------+-------------+
| contact_id | school_id | key_contact |
+------------+-----------+-------------+
| 1          | 1         | 1           |
| 2          | 2         | 0           |
| 3          | 2         | 1           |
| 4          | 2         | 1           |
| 5          | 3         | 0           |
+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

I'd like to get it into the following shape where `display_order` is a composite unique index with `school_id`:

```
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| contact_id | school_id | display_order |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 1          | 1         | 1             |
| 2          | 2         | 3             |
| 3          | 2         | 1             |
| 4          | 2         | 2             |
| 5          | 3         | 1             |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

And the logic is if `key_contact = 1` then `display_order` should be 1, unless a `contact_id` with the same `school_id` already has a `display_order` with the value of 1, then it should insert the next incrementally available value that would be unique to the `school_id`. I'd then like to insert all contacts where `key_contact = 0` assigning the next available `key_contact` integer unique to the `school_id`.

I've created a unique index for the two columns:

```
UNIQUE KEY `contact_school_display_order_school_id_unique` (`display_order`,`school_id`)
```

I've tried using `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but I really want something that will, on duplicate key, increment the value of the insert value to the next integer that is unique to the `school_id`.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if there is no key contact for a school, like the school with *school_id=3* in your example?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel where key_contact = 0 and it is the only contact for the school, then it should have a display_order of 1. All contacts should have a display order, but key contacts should be ranked higher (lower number!) than non key contacts for the same school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrate from table `contacts1` to `contacts2`

```sql
insert into contacts2
    select 
        c1.contact_id,
        c1.school_id,
        count(c2.contact_id) as display_order
    from contacts1 c1
    join contacts1 c2
        on  c2.school_id = c1.school_id
        and (
            c2.key_contact > c1.key_contact
            or
            c2.key_contact = c1.key_contact and c2.contact_id <= c1.contact_id
        )
    group by c1.contact_id, c1.school_id
    order by c1.contact_id;
```

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5004b1/1)

**Explanation**

The key logic is in the join condition:

```sql
            c2.key_contact > c1.key_contact
            or
            c2.key_contact = c1.key_contact and c2.contact_id <= c1.contact_id
```

This condition defines that the row from `c2` has a higher or equal contact priority for the given school compared to the row from `c1`. (The priority is only equal if the `contact_id` is the same.) In the `SELECT` part we count all the rows with a higher or equal priority for each contact_id from c1 (`group by c1.contact_id`).

```sql
            c2.key_contact > c1.key_contact
```

is only true if `c1.key_contact=0` and `c2.key_contact=1`. So every row from `c2` found by this condition has a higher priority and will be counted.

```sql
            c2.key_contact = c1.key_contact and c2.contact_id <= c1.contact_id
```

If `key_contact` is equal then we only count the rows with a smaller or equal `contact_id`.

This gives you the same result as if you would sort your table like this:

```sql
select *
from contacts1 c1
order by c1.school_id, c1.key_contact desc, c1.contact_id
```

and then enumerate the rows for each school.

Comment: This is beautiful. What is that, velvet? Thank you. Would be doubly grateful if you could illuminate the logic.